# python: simulation termination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just had a quick question, for the following simulation, if one event happens , lets say birth would it automatically increase the time_elapsed, or will it go to death and check the death would happen and do that?

```
while time_elapsed < end_time :
    event=birth () +death () +infection()
    choice=random.random()*event
    choice -= birth()
    time_elapsed += random.expovariate(event)

    if choice < 0 :
        do_birth()
        continue
    choice -= death()
    if choice < 0:
        do_death()
        continue
    choice -= total_infection_rate()
    if choice < 0:
        do_infection()
        continue
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. Can you please explain differently? Thank you

Comment: so what i am trying to say is that, a random variable is generate to see if the even takes place or not.Suppose if the birth could take place, would it check again if the death takes place? or does it go to the beginning and generate a random number again and decide which event takes place

Comment: @user3281911 `continue` takes you immediately back to the top of the `while` loop

Comment: Check out [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html?highlight=random.choice#random.choice) and random.shuffle, you can refactor this code more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, it will check all the conditional statments until any one evaluates to `True`. If it does, it will execute the code in that block and then the `continue` will jump back to the start of the loop, skipping all the other `if` statements (regardless of whether they would have been `True` or not). If you want to perform only one of the cases, you would do it as:

```
if number >= 0:
    print('Number is positive')
else:
    print('Number is negative')
```

Here, python will evaluate the `if number >= 0` block and if it is `True`, it will print the `'Number is positive'` and then skip the `else` statement. If `if number >= 0` block had evaluated to `False`, python would simply execute the code in the `else` block and then move on.

For more detailed cases, you can also use `elif`. Here is a similar example:

```
if number > 0:
    print('Number is positive')
elif number < 0:
    print('Number is negative')
else:
    print('Number is 0')
```

It follows the same logic. Python will start at the top of the block and keep evaluating each condition in the `if`/`elif` blocks until any condition evaluates to `True`, at which point it will execute the code under that block and then skip all the other conditional statements in that group.